# Amazon SES emails marked as spam only when Source field is formatted to have a name

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-simple-email-service

I'm using Amazon SES for sending an email. When setting the `Source` field to use just an e-mail it works properly and the email gets sent to the primary mailbox:

`Source: 'hello@mysite.com',`

However when I try to use a name instead with the following formatting, it gets sent to the spam folder:

`Source: '"My Site" <hello@mysite.com>'`

I'm using node.js with the `aws-sdk` library. Any suggestions on where the problem might be?

Comment: We had this problem before, please contact with AWS Support. The might ask you some questions and modify your SES things, Also check your domain reputation. But I must say we are using several AWS services but every time we have issues with SES only :(